Sharing Ktor Resources across server and client in a KMP Project
After trying out Kotlin Multiplatform development with Ktor server and client, I am super confused about the implementation of Type-Safe routing with @Resource classes.
If I understand correctly, there are two parts to a fully type-safe implementation - the server part, which uses ktor-server-resources and the client part, which uses ktor-client-resources
The resource class is defined like so:
import io.ktor.resources.*

@Resource("/articles")
class Articles()

Now, to me, it makes perfect sense to put these resource classes into the shared/commonMain project, but the Ktor docs don't talk about it at all. It all seems like I should duplicate the classes on client and server.
There's no ktor-resources, only ktor-client-resources and ktor-server-resources, both of which expose the io.ktor.resources package. So if I were to put the resources into a shared package, which dependency would I use?
Is something like that even possible?
I would really like to use a fully type-safe routing, but since I can't share the resource classes, it all seems pretty pointless.
I am probably missing something obvious about how Kotlin/JVM dependencies work.

There is an artifact (https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.ktor/ktor-resources) for the resources to be shared. Both server and client resource modules depend on that shared module.

@AlekseiTirman thank you, how did you figure that out? I mean, it only makes sense, but there's not a single mention about it in the docs.

I am a member of the Ktor team.
